# Handle MySQL error in Silverstripe with DB::query

Tags: php, error-handling, silverstripe

I'm looking for a way to catch a MySQL error in Silverstripe 3.1 when executing a query using `DB::query()`

This is the code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE $table SET ,,"; // Syntax error added purposefully
foreach ($update_array as $key => $value) {
    $name = $formHelpers->some_filter($key);
    $content = $formHelpers->some_filter($value);
    $sql .= " $name='$content',";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ",");
$sql .= "WHERE id=$id";

$result = DB::query($sql);
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific in your question. What should change, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to control how a raw SQL error is handled with SilverStripe so you can catch/prevent a message from being displayed. [The second parameter of `DB::query()` is for controlling the error level](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DB.html#_query).

Let's dive a bit further into the SilverStripe code and [look at how the `MySQLDatabase` class handles it](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-MySQLDatabase.html#130-153) (Note that other SQL DB implementations for SilverStripe may handle this differently).

```
public function query($sql, $errorLevel = E_USER_ERROR) {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['previewwrite']) && in_array(strtolower(substr($sql,0,strpos($sql,' '))),
        array('insert','update','delete','replace'))) {

        Debug::message("Will execute: $sql");
        return;
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['showqueries']) && Director::isDev(true)) {
        $starttime = microtime(true);
    }

    $handle = $this->dbConn->query($sql);

    if(isset($_REQUEST['showqueries']) && Director::isDev(true)) {
        $endtime = round(microtime(true) - $starttime,4);
        Debug::message("\n$sql\n{$endtime}s\n", false);
    }

    if(!$handle && $errorLevel) {
        $this->databaseError("Couldn't run query: $sql | " . $this->dbConn->error, $errorLevel);
    }
    return new MySQLQuery($this, $handle);
}
```

By default the error level is `E_USER_ERROR` so it will call a few more bits internally and trigger a user error that is output to the screen (depending on your [`error_reporting` level](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)).

Unfortunately you can't capture the error that is generated (at least not without [setting an error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)) as the property "dbConn" shown as `$this->dbConn->error` is a [protected property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).